# EXC BAD ACCESS while creating a new CharacterSet

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, nscharacterset

I'm trying to write a slugging function which involves stripping out any punctuation characters except for hyphens. I thought the best way to do this would be to create a new `CharacterSet` as follows:

```
import Foundation

extension CharacterSet {

    func subtracting(charactersIn string: String) -> CharacterSet {
        let unwantedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
        return self.subtracting(unwantedCharacters)
    }


}

let punctuationCharactersExcludingHyphen = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.subtracting(charactersIn: "-")

<#slug function using punctuationCharactersExcludingHyphen#>
```

where `slug function` is a function that I've already tested with existing character sets. The problem is that the assignment `let punctuationCharactersExcludingHyphen...` crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2`.

I've noticed that most problems involving this error are caused by some specific syntax error or the like, but I can't find out what it is here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug to me. Building the difference of *any* two
`CharacterSet`s results in an "infinite" recursion and a stack overflow.
Here is a minimal example which causes the crash:

```
let cs1 = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters
let cs2 = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let cs = cs1.subtracting(cs2)
```

A workaround is to use the

```
public mutating func remove(charactersIn string: String)
```

method of `CharacterSet` instead:

```
var punctuationCharactersExcludingHyphen = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters
punctuationCharactersExcludingHyphen.remove(charactersIn: "-")
```

or if you want an extension method:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func subtracting(charactersIn string: String) -> CharacterSet {
        var cs = self
        cs.remove(charactersIn: string)
        return cs
    }
}
```

Comment: This bug is https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2503 and has been fixed in Foundation: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/5201  and a fix is forthcoming for corelibs-foundation: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/pull/680