# Remove punctuation characters from string except for dash in Swift

Tags: swift

I have some code to remove all punctuation characters:

```
mysentence.components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters).joined().components(separatedBy: " ")
```

Now, I am trying to add an exception for the dash character "-". In other words, I want to remove all punctuation EXCEPT for dashes.

It looks like in Java this can be done with replaceall using a regular expression (which admittedly I don't know how to use). How  might I do this in Swift 4?

Comment: A character set is a set. Making a set derived from the punctuation characters set but without the dash is trivial.

Comment: Thank's Matt. Are you suggesting I just replace .punctuationCharacters with my own custom set?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Ah, I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40702492/1187415 (which accidentally is also about the punctuation character set and the dash).

Comment: Awesome! Great find.

Comment: @adev You're right, very similar. However that was apparently before a Swift bug was patched and mine appears to now be post-patch because Hossam's answer below is working well for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you remove dash `-` from `CharacterSet` like:

```
var set = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters
set.remove(charactersIn: "-")
```